# References are not updating - bibtex and texpad

Tags: bibtex

I am new to latex and my references are not updating. Texpad doesn't generate any bbl files either. Why aren't my references updating even when I choose bibtex typesetting?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
First document. This is a simple example, with no 
extra parameters or packages included.

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is "texpad"?  An iPad application?  In order to receive help, we need more information.  Does the same file compile (assuming a `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` command sequence) with the references if you run it from the command line?  Can you post a minimal `.tex` and `.bib` file for others to inspect? (Regarding the last, please see [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl).)

Answer (score 3):

I'm also using TexPad. For your bibliography you need to change the typesetter (upper-left corner of the TexPad window" that is by default at "Auto-detect" to "Bibtex" or to be sure "Bibtex + Makeindex"

Answer (score 1):

Texpad does generate bbl files but they are hidden. Enable viewing hidden files (http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/), and you should find the bbl in a folder called ".texpadtmp". You will find this folder in the same folder as your tex file.

By the way, the latest version of Texpad keeps the bbl file visible for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile using "latexmk" as Typesetter. It will update the bibliography and create the .bbl!

Hope this help!

Comment: What does 'as Typesetter' mean here? Is this a setting of the Textpad application the OP mentioned?